# Can I use the PostSharp DisposableAttribute in a derived class hierarchy

Tags: c#, postsharp

I've got a class structure like the following:

```cs
public abstract class Class1 
{
}
public class Class2 : Class1
{
}
```

Both of these classes could contain objects implementing `IDisposable`.

Is it possible to use the PostSharp DisposableAttribute on the `Class1` class and have `Class2` inherit this aspects functionality.

Comment: What does the documentation of Post sharp says? Did you try using in inherited classes? What happened then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `[Disposable]` aspect is inherited automatically. Having the PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio installed (https://www.postsharp.net/download), you can see the `Class2` type name underlined. Hovering the mouse above the type name shows how PostSharp is enhancing the type.

[image: PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio show how the Class2 type is enhanced]

Also, the following tests are passing:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using PostSharp;
using PostSharp.Patterns.Model;
using System;

namespace DisposableTestProject
{
    public class DisposableDependency : IDisposable
    {
        public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.IsDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    [Disposable]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Child]
        public DisposableDependency DepencencyInClass1 { get; } = new DisposableDependency();
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        [Child]
        public DisposableDependency DepencencyInClass2 { get; } = new DisposableDependency();
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestClass1()
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();

            Assert.IsFalse(class1.DepencencyInClass1.IsDisposed);

            Post.Cast<Class1, IDisposable>(class1).Dispose();

            Assert.IsTrue(class1.DepencencyInClass1.IsDisposed);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestClass2()
        {
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();

            Assert.IsFalse(class2.DepencencyInClass1.IsDisposed);
            Assert.IsFalse(class2.DepencencyInClass2.IsDisposed);

            Post.Cast<Class2, IDisposable>(class2).Dispose();

            Assert.IsTrue(class2.DepencencyInClass1.IsDisposed);
            Assert.IsTrue(class2.DepencencyInClass2.IsDisposed);
        }
    }
}
```